# Disabling wordpress added class

Tags: theme-development

I just started learning how to design WordPress themes and i found out that WordPress automatically adds classes to the HTML tag elements. Is there a way of disabling the automatically added class in WordPress to just your own class

Comment: Which elements specifically? The `body_class` and `post_class` filters are two notable places where you can adjust the class names output by WP. It's also possible that the theme is doing its own thing https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/

Comment: You can add your own classes to the body tag, but it doesn't harm you to keep the ones WordPress adds, and you can do a lot of useful things with it, such as apply CSS  only to certain pages, loggin in or out users etc. Also, if you  remove those classes, plugins will not be able to add  their own classes, and the admin bar may behave strangely, and existing styles may be broken. Ask how to add additional classes, but don't try to remove the existing ones.